# Sync navigation drawer items with fragments

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, navigation-drawer

I've navigation drawer and i also have dashboard activity. Is it possible to go to any activity or fragment either by navigation drawer and dashboard? So when i go through dashboard activity. navigation drawer isn't sync with current activity. So how to sync both?

Comment: post some code please

Comment: thanks,but got my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your navigation drawer activity , you need to put this method and in every fragments you need to return  navigation item index . so it will automatically sync with navigation drawer.

`public void NavigationFocus(int navItemIndex) {
        navigationView.getMenu().getItem(navItemIndex).setChecked(true);
    }`